# Office App design and architecture

Tags: c#, vsto, office365

I have a VSTO application designed like a standard windows app that has Data Access Layer, Business Access Layer,Controller and Different views for showing different excel sheets. Its a very big applications.

Now I am trying to convert the VSTO application to Office Apps. I want to use the Business and Data Access layer as lot of work has been done in Business Layer. Data Access Layer is basiacally a EF layer. Buiness Layer 
access the Data layer using the repository pattern. I need the some guidance on a best way to appraoch for the design for office apps where I can reuse most of the code.

Will MVC be a good fit in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using SharePoint **Provider Hosted App** you are able to use a Web Application from a SharePoint site in Office 365, also the Web Application can have access to the site context, you just need to convert your Windows Application into a Web Application and publish it using a Windows Server or if you prefer you can use Azure. I have tested this approach as a SharePoint App but I'm **not sure if this or a similar approach can work in Word, Excel and PowerPoint**, however you should invest some time researching this, worth the effort.

Here is some good resources that will help you to get involved in the Provider Hosted App development:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/24/sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-walkthrough-part-1-preparation.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx

https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/sharepoint-apps

Using Azure:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn343301(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Office Apps and VSTO add-ins are entirely different things. You will not be able to re-use the code due to the fact that Office Apps are written in JS and HTML(+CSS). See [Build apps for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.